# eclipse oxygen - Launch error: Binary not found

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-oxygen

Whenever I create a new project it doesn't include the binaries thing and I get this error: "Launch Failed: Binary not found"

I have already tried changing run configurations to no avail. I have the debug folder but in it is a mysterious stringTest.o file which cannot run the project.

I have built the project several times.

I am using the latest version of Eclipse Oxygen and the MinGW compiler (GNU for Windows).

I have searched for half an hour around and all the methods I've tried haven't worked. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there are no linker errors? Try creating a new project, writing a hello world program, build, and run?

Comment: The `.o` file is the file generated by the compiler. The linker is then used on those files to generate a `.exe` file.

Comment: Your suggestion worked! But I still have some problems, see my other comment.

Comment: If this does not work for existing projects, you might have accidentally corrupted them. Try copying the code over to a new project. If your compiler does not show up when you create a new project, you might need to make sure your `PATH` environment variable includes the path to your compiler's binaries. The code analysis on Eclipse is a little slow sometimes especially with the `using namespace std;` line, and I find saving the file and waiting for a moment usually fixes it.

Answer (score -1):

To Compile and Build the project in Eclipse do

```
Project -> Build Project
```

Then to run the project right click on your source code file and select

```
Run As -> Local C/C++ Application
```

Comment: Hi this works for new projects but not on my existing ones. Also, when I try to create a HelloWorld project with the HelloWorld template I can't choose a compiler, the space is just white. And... in my editor it says "Symbol 'std' could not be resolved" and the same thing for 'cout'.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure then